# No sound on imac g5 (2005), running ubuntu mate 15.10

Tags: sound, soundcard, powerpc

I have no sound.

There are no devices in sound settings, and gnome-alsamixer does not show any sound cards (alsamixer was not found by apt-get).

I have tried the advice in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#Why_do_I_have_no_sound.3F. Without any success, I have restored everything relating to modules to default.

Does anyone have any idea how to get sound working? As far as I can tell, I have tried everything that comes up googling the problem, and which seems relevant to my situation.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the sound to work on a PowerMac G5 with Ubuntu MATE 16.04. Start by listing all the modules related to sound with `lsmod | grep snd`. It shall contain all these

```
snd-powermac 
snd-aoa 
snd-aoa-fabric-layout
snd-aoa-soundbus
snd-aoa-i2sbus
snd-aoa-codec-tas
```

If it doesn't then that might be the reason why your sound doesn't work. You can modprobe these into the live session. Type:

```
$ sudo modprobe snd-powermac
$ sudo modprobe snd-aoa 
$ sudo modprobe snd-aoa-fabric-layout
$ sudo modprobe snd-aoa-soundbus
$ sudo modprobe snd-aoa-i2sbus
$ sudo modprobe snd-aoa-codec-tas
```

Now check and see if the sound works. If it does then we have to put these into `/etc/modules` so they load at startup. Open `/etc/modules` in your favorite text editor and add:

```
snd-powermac
snd-aoa 
snd-aoa-fabric-layout
snd-aoa-soundbus
snd-aoa-i2sbus
snd-aoa-codec-tas
```

Restart the computer to insure that modules are indeed loaded on boot. In case it doesn't then you might have blacklisted them somewhere. You can find the file containing the text "i2sbus" with `sudo grep -rnw '/etc' -e "i2sbus"`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will have a chance to test it out in a couple weeks, I will post back as to whether it resolves the issue.